# Problem with gfortran: unable to obtain libquadmath for Mac Big Sur

Tags: gcc, fortran, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

I recently bought the MacBook Air with M1 processor and Big Sur as OS.

I am trying to build a library which requires gcc and gfortran. I did not have gfotran, so I run a

```
brew install gcc
```

which led to the following libraries under the home-brew installing path (*/opt/homebrew/Cellar*):

[list of libraries downloaded with gcc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJD02.jpg)

However I cannot find the `libquadmath.dylib`. I also tried to download this
[gfortran experimental release for ARM Big Sur](https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases/tag/11-arm-alpha2)

I cannot seem to be able to have the `libquadmath.dylib`.

Answer (score 3):

I am running an Intel Mac on MacOS Big Sur and I had the same issue.

Apparently all `gfortran` libraries are stored inside the gcc directory (or Cellar if you are using Homebrew).

For me the issue was that `/usr/local/gfortran/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib` was missing even though all gfortran dependencies were installed inside the gcc directory.

Using `locate libquadmath.0.dylib` I could find all files with that name on my system. The first time you run `locate` it will take a while and will generate a search index in the background.

I found that `/usr/local/lib/gcc/11/libquadmath.0.dylib` exists and I could just add a link to the existing files:

```
ln /usr/local/lib/gcc/11/libquadmath.0.dylib /usr/local/gfortran/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib
```

*Before being able to create the link I had to create the directory `/usr/local/gfortran/lib/`.*

Comment: For my M1, I did not have the libquadmath in the gcc directory. However, I had installed Anaconda Python, and I found the library in "~/opt/anaconda3/lib/" (using locate). I created a link as per your answer for both libquadmath.0.dylib and libquadmath.dylib, and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
cp /usr/local/lib/gcc/12/libquadmath.0.dylib /Users/***/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib
```

solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, I look for libquadmath path using this command:

```
LIBQUADMATH := $(shell $(FLINK) -print-file-name=libquadmath.a)
```

And I use this variable to set static flag value dynamically:

```
STATIC_FLAG = -static-libgfortran -static-libgcc -lgfortran -lgcc -lSystem -Wl,-no_compact_unwind $(LIBQUADMATH)
```